# Enabling auto_log_stacks on Sentry for python app

Tags: sentry

According to Sentry's Documentation here: https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/clients/python/integrations/logging/

Under the usage head they recommend not to use auto_log_stacks=true but it is not said why they do not recommend this. Does anyone know any issues about using this option in live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some cases where `inspect.stack()` (the functionality used by Sentry to fetch the callstack) might be inaccurate.

For example, if you're using the logging handler integration, which is the most common way `captureMessage` would get called, it's possible that the point in which `emit()` is called has a differing stacktrace from the original call. This isn't very common, but its highly dependent on how the logging stack is being used.

Additionally the calls to `inspect.stack()` aren't free. The performance costs aren't considerable, but its worth noting.

The primary reason we (Sentry) pushes back on this kind of functionality is that often captureMessage is not needed. It's primarily used with logging, and Sentry is not intended to aggregate logs. The only truly supported case would be something like `log.warning()` which is something we feel is actionable, but not an exception.